# Weblogic doesn't close files (but does close connections)

Tags: java, socket, aix, weblogic

Dears,

we're running into a 'too many open files' issue.

We've made some progress but the issue is still there...

We use cxf on weblogic on aix.

relevant cxf configuration:

```
<http-conf:conduit name="*.http-conduit">
    <http-conf:client Connection="close" />
</http-conf:conduit>
```

When executing this code:

```
        for(int i=0;i<1300;i++){
            response = callService(request).call();
        }
```

(we don't intend to use this code in production but it's to troubleshoot the issue)

-> the first run succeeds;

-> the second run exposes the problem

output of:

```
   netstat| wc -l
```

first showed that too many sockets remained open (hence the cxf config change)

now the open sockets remain stable +- 400 lines where before the config change >1000

but...

```
lsof 2> /dev/null|grep TCP|wc -l
```

exposes the issue we run into for the present moment

the number of open sockets is stable (so sockets get closed) but the number of open files doesn't...

from 319 just after managed server boot until +-1688 when following exception is raised:

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: NullPointerException invoking https://tst-cjcsr.just.fgov.be/cjcs-cg-ws/1.0-rc2/: null
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:158)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy302.requestCriminalRecord(Unknown Source)
    at be.fgov.just.cjr.application.dossier.DossierBean$1.call(DossierBean.java:226)
    at be.fgov.just.cjr.application.dossier.DossierBean$1.call(DossierBean.java:222)
    at be.fgov.just.cjr.application.dossier.DossierBean.callService(DossierBean.java:153)
    at be.fgov.just.cjr.application.dossier.DossierBean.search(DossierBean.java:99)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:329)
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:342)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstPropertySuffix.invoke(AstPropertySuffix.java:58)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:96)
    at org.jboss.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:409)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at be.fgov.just.cjr.application.authentication.UserbeanEnforceFilter.doFilter(UserbeanEnforceFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at be.fgov.just.cjr.application.authentication.openam.OpenAmPingFilter.doFilter(OpenAmPingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at be.fgov.just.cjr.application.authentication.openam.OpenAmReverifyFilter.doFilter(OpenAmReverifyFilter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at be.fgov.just.cjr.application.authentication.openam.OpenAmSessionFilter.doFilter(OpenAmSessionFilter.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3748)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3714)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2283)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2182)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1491)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:263)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: NullPointerException invoking https://tst-cjcsr.just.fgov.be/cjcs-cg-ws/1.0-rc2/: null
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor108.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:527)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:1346)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1335)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:632)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:572)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:481)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:382)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:335)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:136)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:459)
    at weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(SOAPHttpsURLConnection.java:37)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:1038)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.getResponseCode(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:266)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.doProcessResponseCode(HTTPConduit.java:1550)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1579)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1520)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1317)
    ... 66 more
```

if more info is to be provided, just ask,

any aid in troubleshooting this issue is greatly appreciated,

restarting the managed server 'solves' the problem but this is no option in production...

TIME_WAIT is set to 1 (15 seconds) so no solution there...

S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in that version of CXF (I tried and found the problem in both 3.0.4 and 3.0.12). Downgrading CXF to 2.6.2 resolved the issue for me. (I have not tried it in a 3.1.x version.)